# Converting base64 image to an actual image with using only libraries java comes with

Tags: java, swing, base64

I'm creating an easter egg for an java swing application, it's will be used primarily internally.

I was planning on taking an image and converting it into base64, then when the easter egg is found, it'll convert the base64 image to an actual image, then finally have it show up in a JFrame or a dialog box. I know it's not that great, but I really don't have much time to do something, plus it was all that came up in my head.

I looked online for anything that does this, and I've found many tutorials showing Base64 decoding to an image, but they all involve external libraries. Is there a way to decode a base64 image to an actual image with using the libraries java comes with?

----------------------- EDIT -----------------------------

Using @IanRoberts comment: "There is a (rather well hidden) base64 encoder/decoder in the parse/printBase64Binary methods of `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`."

I was able to decode the image. [Here](http://pastebin.com/i8S9kAGi) is a pastebin of what I did.

Comment: Would a single Java file (so no extra jars or anything) be good enough? iharder.net/base64

Comment: There is a (rather well hidden) base64 encoder/decoder in the parse/printBase64Binary methods of `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would have been fine with that, but I feel that if someone were to go through the code and see that there was a class specifically devoted to Base64 decoding somebody will notice.

Comment: @chudapati09: Is that really a problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I don't mean to sound picky, but I'm trying to hide the image as much as I can. So having an extra class out there makes it easier to find.

Comment: @IanRoberts, Thanks for that. Using that library I was able to figure out what to do. I edited my original post with a link to a pastebin of what I did.

Comment: @chudapati09: I just suspect that if people are really *reading through the code* they'll notice it whatever you do. If they're not reading through the code, you can hide it anywhere. (Heck, you could rename it easily enough. Give it boring name and no-one will look.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, You do make a valid point. And yes the project is really big and the file could easily get lost. But no offense, but if they were looking for an easter egg, I would have them rather work for it, than have it there in one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses only Java 6 core `java.` and `javax.` classes:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

String base64String = "...";
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String);
ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(bin);
// NB ImageIO doesn't close the provided input stream, but ByteArrayInputStream
// doesn't need to be closed anyway so it doesn't matter.
```

Comment: Thanks,  I just saw that you just posted this.

Answer (score 0):

A rather complex solution to hide an image in a java class, without including the file itself or using base64 (thus reducing the class java file size), is to use the following java program tool to convert an image to a collection of java byte arrays and method invocations that will assemble the original image:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ImageDataGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] params) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (params.length != 2) {
            System.out.printf("Uso: java ImageDataGenerator <nombre_imagen> <archivo_imagen>\n");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String imageName = params[0];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(params[1]);
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("imgData.txt");

        p.printf("   private byte[] get%sPart1() {\n", imageName);
        p.printf("       return new byte[] {");

        int readed = 0;
        int writed = 0;
        int numMethods = 1;
        while ((readed = fis.read()) != -1) {
            if (writed < 3000) {
                p.printf("%d,", (byte) readed);
            } else {
                writed = 0;
                p.printf("%d};\n", (byte) readed);
                p.printf("   }\n");
                numMethods++;
                p.printf("   private byte[] get%sPart%d() {\n", imageName, numMethods);
                p.printf("       return new byte[] {\n ");
            }

            if ((++writed % 500) == 0) {
                p.printf("\n");
            }
        }
        p.printf("};\n");
        p.printf("   }\n\n");

        p.println("    private BufferedImage createImageFromArrays(byte[]... arrays) throws IOException { ");
        p.println("        int size = 0;");
        p.println("        for (byte[] array : arrays) size = array.length;");
        p.println("        byte[] imageInByte = new byte[size];");
        p.println("        int pos = 0;");
        p.println("        for (byte[] array : arrays) {");
        p.println("            System.arraycopy(array, 0, imageInByte, pos, array.length);");
        p.println("            pos += array.length;");
        p.println("        }");
        p.println("        ");
        p.println("        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);");
        p.println("        return ImageIO.read(in);");
        p.println("    }");
        p.println("\n");

        p.println("// Insert this call anywhere in your code");
        p.printf("createImageFromArrays(");
        for (int i = 1; i <= numMethods; i++)
            p.printf("get%sPart%d()%s ", imageName, i, i <= numMethods - 1 ? "," : "");
        p.printf(");");

        p.flush();
        p.close();
    }
}
```

Use the tool typing: `java ImageDataGenerator hiddenImage /path/to/image/image.png`

It will generate a file named `imgData.txt` which content you must copy/paste inside your  `JFrame` class declaration section. The last line of the generated file will contain a call to a method named `createImageFromArrays` which you must invoke in your `JFrame` onShow/onLoad event listener

(I used this tool before to hide images/resources in J2ME applications, hope it helps)